# Why, when making the viewbox smaller, does my SVG get bigger?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/akcp8z7w/

Where I have an SVG icon with the following attributes :

```
x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
```

This icon is central on the page. However when I make the viewbox smaller like so :

```
viewBox="0 0 12 12"
```

Corresponding fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/akcp8z7w/1/

It makes the icon bigger. Why is this :

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Totally normal. I would try to illustrate it (using only width)

let's imagine you have (viewBox 0-24, width = 100)

```
| - A B - | - C D - | - E F - | - G H - |
0         6        12        18        24
```

When you limit (viewBox 0-12, width : 100 (unchanged)), it looks bigger, you get :

```
|   -   A   B   -   |   -   C   D   -   |
0                   6                  12
```

When you limit (viewBox : 0-12, width : 50), you get :

```
| - A B - | - C D - |
0         6        12
```

This could be see as Clipping :
[image]

If you did not want it looks bigger, you should indicate the width of your box. And if you want to display 2 times less content, you should indicate a width 2 times smaller.

Finally what you need to understand is :

- a SVG is a set of points in a 2D space
- viewBox attribute is the coordinates of the min/max displayed coordinates

On the other hand :

- you can give this rectangle (the viewBox) the size you want when you specify width/height.

Without specifying anything, you get a default width and the less you display, the bigger it is (to fill all available space).

Comment: thanks for the response. How come if i set the width and height to 24, and a viewbox of "0 0 24 24" it works fine, scales okay, where as if i replace 24 by 12, i.e width & height = 12 and viewbox ="0 0 12 12", the icon doesnt get scaled properly ? See https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/akcp8z7w/3/

Comment: Do you want to display less content ? Or to display all the content in a smaller box ?

Comment: Im just trying to understand what is happening. I gathered, if i have a width and height of, say 12, and a viewbox with a width and height of 12, it would resize to be half over the original, 24 width and height, but it doesnt seem to

Comment: Does my last edit help you to understand it ?